# conditional expectation of default

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am really confused about how to work out the following.

Consider two loans A and B with the same probability of default p(either 0 or 1) in this case p or (1-p) and a default
correlation r.
(a)  Show that the conditional default probability of loan A given that
loan B defaults is
p + r(1 - p):

Answer : I have tried the following

Create a table
                B
              0       1
A 0     (1-p)^2      p*r*(1-p)
  1     r *p*(1-p)   p^2

But I cant show the proof,
How to incorporate the r(correlation) to expectation?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want people that don't know what "probability of default" is, then I suggest you define this in your question.

Comment: I did it :D No need to answer